# Compare ratings of players over different leagues?

Tags: mean, paired-data, cross-section, rating

I want to compare ratings of players from different leagues and predict rating of player in a league he/she didn't participate in. Rating of a player is estimated within a league where he was playing.
There are some *cross-observations* which are players that have ratings estimated for more then one league.

For example there is a player P1 who has a rating 40 in league L1 and rating 55 in league L2. As you can see at the picture. There are distributions of rating in L1 and L2. Yellow line indicates the mean rating of a league and the green lines are *cross-observations* .

[image: distribution of players ratings in a league L1 resp. L2]

My question is if I know that player Px has a rating R in L1, what is his rating in L2?

Any ideas are appreciated!

Comment: What kind of rating is this? Elo ratings have some underlying assumptions which might give an approach, but others are compiled in a different basis

Comment: This rating is achieved by DTMC model based on players "doings" in a game. I am not looking for anything complicated at the moment. Maybe some average over the difference of ratings of players and then cross-multiplication?